# Checking if Null

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a very simple question, but because I've only been doing this language for a week, the answer has not come to me. An error occurs in between the following two lines, because `Regex` is randomly null, but how would I check if it's null, so itd doesn't throw an error?

```js
var Regex = /\<span class="currency-robux">([\d,]+)\<\/span\>/
var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex)[1]
```

Comment: I searched for null, but couldn't find it. I literally searched 2 minutes ago. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1348195) for extra credit.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: He's not parsing it, but just matching a part of it - for which regex is fine.

Comment: It is in a for loop. After checking if it is null, assuming it is, it would just go to the next item in the loop, right?

Comment: @Bergi How is that not parsing HTML with regex? Writing a regular expression for something you _already_ have a data structure you can query for seems silly. The easiest thing to do in his case would be to do `document.querySelector(".currency-robux").textContent` anyway. ( One extra `createDocumentFragment` line and then query that if it's not in the DOM yet). No heart attacks if you have a space after the word `class` or multiple classes, or several attributes.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Depends on whether the string is from a DOM or not. And it's not "parsing" like in the question you linked, where it was tried to express the language syntax of HTML in regex - which is not done here, it expects a particular span.

Comment: @Bergi Do you honestly believe a regular expression is the best tool for this task? It could go wrong in so many ways where throwing it into a fragment and querying it is dead simple and a lot less fragile...

Comment: No, but depending on the circumstances it could be the simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var Regex = /<span class="currency-robux">([\d,]+)<\/span>/;
var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex);
PriceSelling = PriceSelling ? PriceSelling[1] : '';

if (PriceSelling.length < 1) {
    alert('Nothing!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing that part, but it is in a for loop, and it is not letting me use the continue statement to skip over that ID because it is "Illegal". How would I fix that?

Comment: @user3341815 Instead of `< 1`, just use `> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could either do it in two steps:

```
var result = data.match(Regex);
var PriceSelling = result != null ? result[1] : undefined;
```

or use the OR operator to use an empty array as the default result:

```
var PriceSelling = (data.match(Regex) || [])[1];
```